# Manipulating BitmapData, only 1/3rd gets altered

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, system.drawing

My goal is to load my 256x256 pixel sized bitmap and assign for each pixel either a  white or black color value, depending on whether the actual value falls below  a certain threshold.

Problem is, only 1/3 of the width the bitmap has the new pixel data, even though the inner for-statement iterates over the whole width.

```
unsafe
{
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0, 256, 256), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Height; j++)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0 + (j * bitmapData.Stride);
        for (int k = 0; k < bitmapData.Width; k++)
        {
            if (row[k] <= TresholdFilter)
                row[k] = 0;
            if (row[k] > 0)
                row[k] = 255;
        }
    }
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}
```

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: What's the value of `TresholdFilter`?

Comment: It's an Int32, with a range 0-255

Comment: It's possible that, in some cases, in your `row[k]` remains the initial value? Have you tried with another image?

Comment: It looks like your bitmap is rgb, so no "white" pixels there, white when all three color parts of pixel are 255.

Comment: What's the value of bitmap.PixelFormat? Format24bppRgb by any Chance?

Comment: Yes, it's Format24bppRgb. I haven't checked that value, but this is what my camera's native method sets as the bitmap imageformat, even though its a black and white image (mono8)

Comment: There you go. You found your solution. Reading one byte at a time, when each pixel in the image is described by 3 Bytes, isn't the best idea. Explains why you only transform a third of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you treat a 24bpp image as 8bpp. Each Pixel is described by 3 Bytes, not one. The code could be modified in the following way:

```
unsafe
{
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0, 256, 256),ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Height; j++)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0 + (j * bitmapData.Stride);
        for (int k = 0; k < bitmapData.Width * 3; k += 3)
        {
            if (row[k] <= TresholdFilter)
            {
               row[k] = 0;
               row[k + 1] = 0;
               row[k + 2] = 0;
            }
            if (row[k] > 0)
            {
               row[k] = 255;
               row[k + 1] = 255;
               row[k + 2] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}
```

Just to be sure you could check if `row[k], k + 1 and k + 2` are all below/above the `ThresholdFilter`, but you only need that if it could happen that the image isn't grayscaled.

Additionally you should probably check at the beginning if the image is in fact in 24bppRgb format to avoid crashing the application if it actually isn't.